# Add Form with Dynamic HTML on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, dynamic-html

I have a website app http://firstusadata.com/cash_flow_test/ that I would like to add some functionality to, yet have been unsuccessful.

The idea is to be able to add a vendor information form with one button click, and then be able to add products to that specific vendor information form with a different button click. The image below shows the Vendor Information Button as well as the add product button.

[Vendor and Product Button areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqAsX.png)

Currently if I remove the dynamic html function for the vendor information form (div id="dynamic_content_1"), as seen below, the add product button works and it will append the new product line underneath the previous. I believe my error is located somewhere in this area, but I am unsure.

```js
function dynamic_html(){
   var content =  '<div id="dynamic_content_1">'                    
  +'<div class="row">'
   +'<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 SecPageMain">'
               +'<h3>Vendor Information</h3>'
    +'<form method="post" action="http://firstusadata.com/cash_flow/companies/insert_company_information">'
     +'<div class="row margin_top_25">'
      +'<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
       +'<p>Name of Company:</p>'
      +'</div>' 
      +'<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">'
       +'<input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100" name="company_name" required='' >'
      +'</div>'
     +'</div>'
     +'<div class="row margin_top_25">'
      +'<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
       +'<p>Company Phone Number:</p>'
      +'</div>'
          
      +'<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">'
       +'<input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100" id="" name="company_phone" required='' >'
      +'</div>'
     +'</div>'
     +'<div class="row margin_top_25">'
      +'<div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
       +'<p>Did this company build your website?</p>'
      +'</div>'
          
      +'<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">'
       +'<div class="radio radio-info radio-inline" >'
        +'<input type="radio"  value="1" name="built_website">'
        +'<label for="inlineRadio1"> Yes </label>'
       +'</div>'
       +'<div class="radio radio-inline">'
        +'<input type="radio"  value="0" name="built_website" checked>'
        +'<label for="inlineRadio2"> No </label>'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
     +'</div>'
     +'<div class="hide" id="BuildWebsite" >'
      +'<div class="row margin_top_10">'
       +'<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
        +'<p>Website URL:</p>'
       +'</div>'
           
       +'<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">'
        +'<input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100" id="website_url" name="website_url">'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
      
      +'<div class="row margin_top_10">'
       +'<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
        +'<p>Type of Website:</p>'
       +'</div>'
           
       +'<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">'
        +'<select class="form-control w100" id="type_of_website" name="type_of_website">'
         +'<option value="Amazon Store">Amazon Store</option>'
         +'<option value="Affiliate">Affiliate</option>'
         +'<option value="Drop Ship">Drop Ship</option>'
         +'<option value="Lead Generation">Lead Generation</option>'
         +'<option value="Small Business">Small Business</option>'
         +'<option value="Landing Page">Landing Page</option>'
        +'</select>'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
      
      +'<div class="row margin_top_10 category_area" style="display:none">'
       +'<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
        +'<p>Category:</p>'
       +'</div>'
       
       +'<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">'
        +'<select class="form-control w100" id="website_category" name="website_category">'
         +'<option value="">Select category</option>'
        +'</select>'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
      
      +'<div class="row margin_top_10">'
       +'<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
        +'<p>Average Profit Margin Per 100 Users:</p>'
       +'</div>'
           
       +'<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">'
       +' <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100 price" id="average_profit" name="average_profit">'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
     +'</div>'
     
     +'<div id="dynamic_content_2">'
      +'<div class="row margin_top_25 form-inline product_row">'
       +'<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">'
        +'<div class="form-group w100">'
         +'<input type="" class="form-control  w100" id="" name="product_name[]" placeholder="Product"  required>'
        +'</div>'
       +'</div>'
       
       +'<div class="col-sm-2">'
        +'<div class="form-group  w100">'
         +'<input type="" class="form-control w100 price" id="" name="product_price[]" placeholder="Price"  required>'
        +'</div>'
       +'</div>'
       
       +'<div class="col-sm-3">'
        +'<select class="form-control w100" name="product_type[]" required>'
         +'<option value="">Select</option>'
         +'<option value="Web Development">Web Development</option>'
         +'<option value="Business Development">Business Development</option>'
        +'</select>'
       +'</div>'
       
       +'<div class="col-sm-3">'
        +'<div class="btn-inline margin_left_25">'
         +'<button type="button" class="btn plusbtn btn-default pull-left">'
          +'<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>'
         +'</button>'
         
         +'<button type="button" class="btn btn-default minusbtn pull-left">'
          +'<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>'
         +'</button>'
        +'</div>' 
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
     +'</div>'
                    
                    
           +'<h4>Add Vendor</h4>'         
            +'<div class="col-sm-3">'
        +'<div class="btn-inline margin_left_25">'
         +'<button type="button" class="btn testbutton1 btn-default pull-left">'
          +'<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>'
         +'</button>'
         
         +'<button type="button" class="btn btn-default testbutton2 pull-left">'
          +'<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>'
         +'</button>'
        +'</div>'
       +'</div>'                 
    +'</form>'
   +'</div>'
  +'</div>'
       +' </div>';
   return content;
  }
```

I am fairly knew to jquery, so I may be missing something very obvious to those more experienced, I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: So, What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: *..it will append the new product line underneath the previous. I believe my error is located somewhere in this area, but I am unsure.* What Error ?

Comment: I cannot get the "Add Vendor" button to work with the "Add Product" button. I can only get the "Add Product" button to work and that is only if I remove the dynamic html shown above.     How can I get both of these button to work properly?

Comment: Unfortunately it is saying that my code is too long to add as a comment. You can view the page on http://firstusadata.com/cash_flow_test/ and then click view source to access the full code.

Comment: I have added the code to jsfiddle I hope this is able to help https://jsfiddle.net/uLk7p009/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in your fiddle, you have dynamic_html() defined twice. Your page should raise an error (f12 to open the console if you want to see this yourself).

Also this line

```
+'<input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100" name="company_name" required='' >'
```

needs to have double quotes for the required field.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and information. what would be the proper way to define a new dynamic_html() element? Any google searches for "how to define dynamic_html" only webster dictionary definitions of dynamic_html.

Comment: Specifically, how would I go about naming these two different dynamic_html() functions, and their corresponding click events

Comment: First click event`$(document).on("click",".plusbtn",function(){
   $("#dynamic_content_2").append(dynamic_html());
  });`
Used to append this dynamic_html()
  `function dynamic_html(){
   var content = '<div class="row margin_top_25 dynamic_content_2 form-inline">'
      +'<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">'
       +'<div class="form-group w100">'
        +'<input type="" class="form-control  w100" id="" name="product_name[]" placeholder="Product" required >'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'

   return content;
  }`

Comment: Second click event `$(document).on("click",".testbutton1",function(){
   $("#dynamic_content_1").append(dynamic_html());
  });` Used to append this second section of dynamic_html() `function dynamic_html(){
   var content =  '<div id="dynamic_content_1">'                    
  +'<div class="row">'
   +'<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 SecPageMain">'
               +'<h3>Vendor Information</h3>'
    +'<form method="post" action="http://firstusadata.com/cash_flow/companies/insert_company_information">'
return content;
}`

Comment: @PaulCunningham the function is just a function like any other. Call it what you will. You see similar naming conventions but you could just as easily call one of them purpleElephant(). (Your function is simply returning a string and accepting no arguments. You could also store this value in a variable and use that instead of a function with your current implementation. That is, instead of defining and returning the content variable in your function, you could simply define it in a larger scope to avoid having to call a function)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by properly naming the dynamic_html() functions and adding the double quotes as J. Bush had suggested.

Thank you for all of your help everyone! Glad to have an awesome community like this available as a resource.